# Hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate

Tags: linux, debian, firmware

I started installing Debian on my laptop, and it showed that I have missing firmware.

> Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. Those
>   are:
>
> ```
> ath10/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin
> ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
> ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin
> ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin
> ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin
> ```

What should I do with it?

Comment: If you don't have a problem with non-free firmware, install the firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free here is "free as in speech" not "free as in beer". You don't need to pay for them, it is just you don't have all the rights to those binaries that you have to the rest of the system.

If you don't have a problem with that go ahead and install them.